# Angular2 animation - unable to animate on ngFor loop on component

Tags: angularjs, angular, animation

I need help please. I have read a lot on animation in angular and have applied it successfully on simple solutions. In my search for over 45 min I am unable to find a question that relates to my situation.

I have a main component called **CareerListingComponent**. It gets job offers (career) from service. Then it prints box for each job using **ngFor** loop using another component called **CareerBoxComponent**.

**CareerListingComponent** has dropdown using which you can shortlist your selection: -

```
<select class="form-control" id="idSelDepartment" name="dept" 

    [ngModel]="searchDept" (ngModelChange)="selectValueChangedDept($event)">

            <option value="">Career Area - All</option>
            <option *ngFor="let dept of arrDept" value="{{dept}}">{{dept}}</option>
</select>
```

Everything works fine except animation. If I select something from dropdown, boxes show and hide but boxes change very fast with no effects.

I have used "SearchPipe:searchCountry:searchCity:searchDept" **Pipes to filter array of Careers object**.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container grid jobs">

      <app-career-box

        *ngFor="let career of careers | SearchPipe:searchCountry:searchCity:searchDept
          let index = index;
          let isOdd = odd;
          let isEven= even;"

        [@visibilityChanged]="'in'"
        [career]="career"

      ></app-career-box>

    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am using the property **[@visibilityChanged]="'in'"** to fadeIn and fadeOut but it does not work.

My animation code in the **CareerListingComponent** is

```
animations:   [
                trigger('visibilityChanged', [
                    state('in' , style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'scale(1.0)' })),
                    state('out', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0.0)'  })),
                    transition('1 => 0', animate('700ms')),
                    transition('0 => 1', animate('700ms'))

                ])
            ]
```

my guess is that my box component called **CareerBoxComponent** with selector **app-career-box** does not notify parent component about its show and hide.

Source code of **CareerBoxComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector:       'app-career-box',
  templateUrl:    './career-box.component.html',
  styles:         []
})
export class CareerBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() career: Career;
  constructor() { }

  gotoDetailUrl() {
    window.location.href = this.career.detailUrl;
    console.log('Redirect to '+ this.career.detailUrl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why animations are not being applied on your `app-career-box` component is because they are not `block` elements. I may be wrong but applying `display: block;` style on the host does the trick.

Here is how I applied the style on `CareerBoxComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-career-box',
  template: `...`
  styles: [`
  :host {
    display: block;
  }
  `]
})
export class CareerBoxComponent {
}
```

Plunkr Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/RYxZoS6thSO7iaU7YEPK?p=preview